# Tangents to circles: What do I do now? (c) solved, but (a) and (b) are still open for answers...

Tags: geometry, circles, angle, tangent-line

everyone! I am confused about what to do here and how to do it.  May I have some help?
[image: 1]

So, I know that $\overline{FI}$ and $\overline{IE}$ are both radii of the small circle and $\overline{JK}$ and $\overline{JH}$ are both radii of the big circle.  I am pretty sure that the outer tangents are equal, but in this picture, they don't look equal...

Now, I can't proceed.  Could someone help me?

Question (c) solved... (a) and (b) left...

Thank You!

Comment: For the first question, make use of the fact that $CE = CD, BG = BH, FH = EK$ and so on. The second question can also be answered using the same approach.

Comment: You are in a case where you have a triangle ABC, its inscribed circle and one of its **excircles** (remember this keyword). See a related question [here](http://www.gogeometry.com/school-college/3/p1267-triangle-incircle-excircle-90-degree-parallelogram.htm)

Comment: See updated answer for  (a) and (b) .

Comment: Yes, thanks @g.kov, but i didn't really understand it.  Also, I think (don't quote me on this) your solution to question (c) is wrong?  This is because $\overline{BC}$ is more slanted in my diagram than it is in yours, or does this not matter?  The reason I am pointing this out is because $\overline{BC}$ is a perpendicular bisector of $\overline{EK}$ , but in mine, it is just a line going through $\overline{EK}$.  Thank you!

Comment: @MathLover, could you expand on this?  I think it may help if you go into more detail.  Also, once you have it in mind, could you post it as an answer to my question.  This will really help, thanks.

Comment: Did you actually read the answer?
If yes, then why on Earth do you have an opinion that
"$\overline{BC}$  is a perpendicular bisector of $\overline{EK}$"?
The angle $\gamma$ in the diagram is about $85.2^\circ$,
but it neither matter nor is used in the proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Extend $AB$, $AC$ to get $\triangle AB_2C_2\sim \triangle ABC$
such that $\bigcirc J$ is the incircle of $\triangle AB_2C_2$.

Then
\begin{align} 
\angle ICB&=\tfrac\gamma2
,\\
\angle BCC_2&=180^\circ-\gamma
,\\
\angle BCJ&=\tfrac12\angle BCC_2
=90^\circ-\tfrac\gamma2
,\\
\text{hence, }\quad
\angle ICJ&=\angle ICB+\angle BCJ=90^\circ
.
\end{align}

---

**Edit**

Let
\begin{align} 
\frac{|JK|}{|IE|}&=
\frac{r_2}{r}
=k
.
\end{align}

Using two expressions for the height $h_2$ of $\triangle AC_2B_2$

\begin{align}
h_2&=h\cdot k=\frac{2S}{a}\cdot k
,\\
h_2&=h+2r_2=
\frac{2S}a+2r\cdot k
,
\end{align}

we get $k$ in terms of semiperimeter $\rho$ of $\triangle ABC$:
\begin{align}
k&=\frac{S}{S-r a}
=\frac{\rho}{\rho-a}
,
\end{align}

thus
\begin{align}
r_2&=\frac{\rho r}{\rho-a}
\end{align}

and we have

\begin{align}
|AH|&=r_2\cot\tfrac\alpha2
=r_2\cdot\frac{|AF|}{|IF|}
=\frac{\rho r}{\rho-a}\cdot\frac{\rho-a}{r}
=\rho
.
\end{align}

\begin{align}
|CD|&=\rho-c
,\\
|BG|&= r_2\cdot \tan\tfrac\beta2
=\frac{\rho r}{\rho-a}
=\frac{\rho r}{\rho-a}\cdot \frac{r}{\rho-b}
\\
&=
\frac{\rho r}{\rho-a}\cdot \frac{r}{\rho-b}
\cdot \frac{\rho(\rho-c)}{\rho(\rho-c)}
\\
&=
\frac{\rho^2 r^2}
{\rho(\rho-a)(\rho-b)(\rho-c)}
\cdot(\rho-c)
=\rho-c
=|CD|
.
\end{align}